# double method inside a generic class in java

Tags: java, generics, casting, double, generic-programming

I am trying to create a generic class that would work with 3 numbers in java (int, float and double in my case).

Inside this class i want a **double** method that would return the maximum number of the 3, but i have trouble returning a double since it's a generic class.

```
class Triple<T extends Comparable> {
    T a;
    T b;
    T c;

    public Triple(T a, T b, T c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    double max() {
        if (a.compareTo(b) > 0 && a.compareTo(c) > 0) {
            return (double) a;
        } else {
            if (b.compareTo(c) > 0) {
                return (double) b;
            } else {
                return (double) c;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is what i have so far, but when testing it with integers, i get the following error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Any help on how to return a primitive type from a generic class?

Comment: Just return T, not double.

Comment: You could declare that your generic type extends `Number`. That has a [`doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue--) method.

Comment: You should return `T` and remove the `double` castings. That should do it.

Comment: unless this is an exercise or something I'd favour --> `double max = DoubleStream.of(firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue)
                         .max()
                         .getAsDouble();` for floats and double and `int max = IntStream.of(firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue)
                         .max()
                         .getAsInt();` for ints, rather then creating a generic solution for this. or.... revert to using the old style `Math.max(num1, Math.max(num2, num3));`

Comment: If you make your class declaration `class Triple<T extends Comparable<T>>` you'll avoid all the raw type warnings.

Comment: @khelwood if I extend Number, then i can't extend Comparable. I'm a beginner in Java, so i'm not sure how to compare those if i don't extend comparable?

Comment: Note that a generic class cannot work with primitive types like `double` and `int`. It will only work with wrapper types like `Double` and `Integer`. Due to autoboxing and autounboxing, the conversion from a primitive type to a wrapper type is often seamless. Attempting to cast is one of the places where you can run into troubles.

Comment: You can declare a generic type that extends both `Number` and `Comparable`, if that's what you want.

Comment: I know what i'm asking sounds a bit pointless, but it's an obstacle i ran into and i'm just trying to resolve it. Btw the method has to be double, i'm aware there are no issues if it is a generic one

Comment: You can have generic extending multiple class or interface like below Triple<T extends Number & Comparable>

Comment: Triple<T extends Number & Comparable> did it for me, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @Filip5991 I just want to emphasize the other change in m17's answer that you accepted: calling `doubleValue()` instead of casting. This is necessary because the generic type is `Integer` or `Double` or `Float` rather than `int`, `double`, or `float`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have generic extends Comparable and Number. This way we can call `doubleValue()` present in Number class instead of casting it into double.

```
class Triple<T extends Number & Comparable> {
    T a;
    T b;
    T c;

    public Triple(T a, T b, T c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    double max() {
        if (a.compareTo(b) > 0 && a.compareTo(c) > 0) {
            return a.doubleValue();
        } else {
            if (b.compareTo(c) > 0) {
                return b.doubleValue();
            } else {
                return c.doubleValue();
            }
        }
    }

}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Triple<Integer> triple = new Triple<>(1, 2, 3);

        System.out.println(triple.max());

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be good to emphasize that this code calls `doubleValue()` instead of casting, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `T` instead of `double`

```
T max() {
    if (a.compareTo(b) > 0 && a.compareTo(c) > 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        if (b.compareTo(c) > 0) {
            return b;
        } else {
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Triple<Integer> test = new Triple<>(1, 4, 5);
       System.out.println(test.max());

       }

}


class Triple<T extends Number<T> & Comparable<T>> {
    T a;
    T b;
    T c;

    public Triple(T a, T b, T c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }


  double max() {
    if (a.compareTo(b) > 0 && a.compareTo(c) > 0) {
        return a.doubleValue();
    } else {
        if (b.compareTo(c) > 0) {
            return b.doubleValue();
        } else {
            return c.doubleValue();
        }
    }
  }

}
```